# vertically center text in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I am trying to make a navigation bar in which the buttons' text will be aligned in the center vertically.

Currently, everything is working fine with the navigation bar besides the vertical align.

I have tried many methods such as with line height, padding to the top and bottom (messes up my heights so the text divs overflow), flex, and table display.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
#nav {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
#nav div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
}
#nav div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="nav">
    <div><a>Home</a></div>
    <div><a>Page2</a></div>
    <div><a>Page3</a></div>
    <div><a>Page4</a></div>
    <div><a>Page5</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the table and table-cell method. Basically you need to add the css property `display: table` to the parent element and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` to the children ones.

*Increased height for demo purpose.*

```css
#nav {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
#nav div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav div:hover {
  background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="nav">
    <div><a>Home</a>
    </div>
    <div><a>Page2</a>
    </div>
    <div><a>Page3</a>
    </div>
    <div><a>Page4</a>
    </div>
    <div><a>Page5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note, there's no need to specify 0px in your css properties. Remember that 0px, 0%, 0em, 0rem, 0pt, or any other unit identifier following zero is optional. In my opinion units in 0 are not needed and it's clearer not to use them. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With flexbox, you were very close.

Because a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) exists only between parent and child, your `display: flex` on the `#nav` container was reaching the `div`s, but not the anchors.

You need to make the individual divs flex containers, as well, so flex alignment properties can apply to the anchor elements.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav {
    height: 10%;  /* This value will hide the nav bar on smaller windows */
    background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex; /* Will apply to child div elements, but not anchor elements */
}

#nav div {
    /* display: inline-block; */
    height: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex: 1;

    display: flex;            /* NEW; nested flex container */
    justify-content: center;  /* NEW; align anchor elements horizontally */
    align-items: center;      /* NEW; align anchor elements vertically */
}

#nav div:hover {
    background-color: rgb(41, 128, 185);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="nav">
        <div><a>Home</a></div>
        <div><a>Page2</a></div>
        <div><a>Page3</a></div>
        <div><a>Page4</a></div>
        <div><a>Page5</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```